# Fontawesome in Bootgrid cell

Tags: font-awesome, jquery-bootgrid

I can set the icons for the Bootgrid command buttons using Fontawesome icons, but can't make a fontawesome icon display in a Bootgrid table cell.

```
<td><i class='fa fa-check'></i></td>
```

I've checked it works outside the Bootgrid table.

Even styling does not work:

```
<td><span style="color:#ff0000!important">x</span></td>
```

Comment: Inspect your `i` element. It's probable that Bootgrid is overriding Font Awesome's `font`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this at the moment and it works:

In the 'formatters' return an html string containing an element with a font awesome class.

```
"clipboard": function(column, row) {
htmlstring = "<i class=\"fa fa-clipboard\" aria-hidden=\"true\" alt=\"Copy to clipboard\"></i>"
return htmlstring
}
```

Hope that helps.

Rob Ganly